# mocking only one call at a time with mockk

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockk

I know that in order to mock how a method responds, you have to use

```
every { instanceX.methodB() } returns "42"
```

I'm trying to mock an iterator, for which you have to mock 2 methods hasNext() and next(), if hasNext() returns true always there will be an infinite loop, if it returns false from the beginning, next() will not return anything.

My question is: is there a way to mock individual calls one by one with mockk, as you can do in mockito ? I couldn't find anything in the docs.

Comment: I'm getting data from cassandra using a library which returns a ResultSet, I need to test my service which is using that data, and I mock this ResultSet.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use `returnsMany` or `andThen` construct with/instead of `return`.

Answer (score 86):

At the excellent post [Mocking is not rocket science](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/mocking-is-not-rocket-science-expected-behavior-and-behavior-verification-3862dd0e0f03) are documented two alternatives:

`returnsMany` specify a number of values that are used one by one i.e. first matched call returns first element, second returns second element:

```
    every { mock1.call(5) } returnsMany listOf(1, 2, 3)
```

You can achieve the same using andThen construct:

```
    every { mock1.call(5) } returns 1 andThen 2 andThen 3
```

Comment: What if I want to be flexible about the number of elements I need?

Comment: How does this apply if I want the first call to throw an exception and the second call to return a value?

Answer (score 5):

Now I have a similar use-case, but for me [`answers`](https://mockk.io/#answers) is the appropriate solution as I already have an `Iterator` in place (and the returned  iterator is actually a custom extension of `Iterator`):

```
every { mock.bogusIterator() /* : CustomIterator */ } answers { 
  val testIterator = testList.iterator() // just an Iterator
  every { hasNext() } answers { testIterator.hasNext() }
  every { next() } answers { testIterator.next() }
}
```

where `testList` contains some predefined values for the test.

`returns` always returns the value that is given to the function at that time. So using `every { hasNext() } returns whatever` will always return the value of `whatever` at that mock declaration time, regardless of whether `whatever` is mutable or not. On the other hand, with `answer` you always get the current value of what you return at the time of calling the function. In case someone gets confused by it ;-) Maybe also my further explanation confuses a bit :-)

Answer (score 3):

I couldn’t answer the @GACy20, so I’m putting the answer to his question here.

Doubt: How does this apply if I want the first call to throw an exception and the second call to return a value?

You just need to do this:

```
every { thing.save(any()) } throws RuntimeException("Erro") andThen aRealValue
```